# Several rows with exact same values but only one column returns different value; How to grab this value and create another column(s) for that?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So Here it is : I joined several tables and get results like this:

```
ContactID    Name    Title      Phone
1234567      John    Manager    999999
1234567      John    Manager    888888
```

I want to get the unique ContactID in my result and put another phone value to 'Phone2'. (There are more than 2, Phone3, Phone4)

So the result I want to see is like this

```
ContactID    Name   Title             Phone    Phone2     Phone3    Phone4...
1234567      John   Manager           999999    888888     NULL      NULL
```

Any help? I tried to use Pivot, but it seems like the aggregate function wont work in this scenario.

Comment: @chue  Thx for the format editing.

Comment: You are welcome.  As you may have noticed, all I did was add 4 spaces at the beginning of each of those lines to make your data much easier to read. You can do this with code as well.

Comment: Are you only going to have 4 phone numbers?  Or can there be more than 4?

Comment: actually its more than 4, it goes to 10..i need to add more columns in order to get the unique ContactID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a PIVOT, although you have to make up a pivot column, for which I use the ROW_NUMBER() function below.  I have allowed for 4 phone numbers below, just expand the pattern, e.g. there are 2 places with `[4]`, if you need to cater for more.

Below I show data coming from a sample table named "data". If you have a complex query, you can first name it using a Common Table Expression, i.e.

```
;with data as (
   <your entire complex query that produces the
    columns: ContactId, Name, Title, Phone>
)
select ContactID, Name, Title,
       [1] as Phone1,
       [2] as Phone2,
       [3] as Phone3,
       [4] as Phone4
  from (
    select ContactID, Name, Title, Phone,
           Row_Number() over (partition by ContactID, Name, Title
                              order by Phone) RN
      from data) p
pivot (max(Phone) for RN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) v;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa02b/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table data (
  ContactID int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Title varchar(10),
  Phone varchar(20));
insert data values
(1234561,      'Jill',    'Employee',    999991),
(1234562,      'Joel',    'Employee',    999992),
(1234567,      'John',    'Manager',    999999),
(1234567,      'John',    'Manager',    888888);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ContactID, Name, Title,
       [1] as Phone1,
       [2] as Phone2,
       [3] as Phone3,
       [4] as Phone4
  from (
    select ContactID, Name, Title, Phone,
           Row_Number() over (partition by ContactID, Name, Title
                              order by Phone) RN
      from data) p
pivot (max(Phone) for RN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) v;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa02b/2/0)**:

```
| CONTACTID | NAME |    TITLE | PHONE1 | PHONE2 | PHONE3 | PHONE4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1234561 | Jill | Employee | 999991 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   1234562 | Joel | Employee | 999992 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   1234567 | John |  Manager | 888888 | 999999 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thx for your help Richard! This works well. But the fact is I joined several tables(inner join table1, table2, table3, and table4)to get those results...(column goes on and on), where do i put the pivot statement? before the inner join or after? Also I have a group clause as well....Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can get all the phone numbers into one column which might be more useful for you depending on your situation.

```
First     Last        Phone
John      Manager     888888,999999,111111
```

See http://www.centrolutions.com/blog/post/2010/03/29/Selecting-Multiple-Rows-as-a-Single-Column-in-SQL.aspx

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is definitely useful. But I actually want to add other columns in the result. Cheers.